# RTL8168B/8111B Lan card is not detected in Redhat..Error is make ***/lib/modules/2.6.18-53.e15/build: no such file or directory stop

Tags: linux

0

Hello friends...

In My computer

Lan card model is Realtek RTL8168B/8111B PCI-E GIGABIT ETHERNET NIC (NDIS 6.20)

My system is dual boot windows 7 and redhat 5.1.Redhat is not picking up this model of Lan card automaticlly.

I tried it by downloading from realtak site for this particular model and find some .tar packages for my kernal and when i tried to install them ...

check old drivers & unload it

build the module and install

make ***/lib/modules/2.6.18-53.e15/build: no such file or directory stop

make[1]: ***[modules] error 2

make : [modules] error 2

i downloaded tar files from sites and unpack according to their instrution i tried to run autorun.sh script as mentioned in readme file but after doing this it is showing above error...

Now what to do i am not getting

Comment: possible duplicate of [RTL8168B/8111B Lan card is  not detected in RHEL5.1..Not finding Lan card driver for this particular family](http://serverfault.com/questions/146462/rtl8168b-8111b-lan-card-is-not-detected-in-rhel5-1-not-finding-lan-card-driver)

Answer (score 1):

- I assume you picked up the [RealTek LINUX driver for kernel 2.6.x and 2.4.x](http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=13&PFid=5&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false#2).
- Then, you followed the README in that tar-ball on your RedHat 5.1.

  - however, it stalled with the Errors you list,
  - **Were you running the `autorun.sh` script as root on RedHat?**
- From your error lines, it seems `Make` could not enter the `lib` directory `2.6.18-53.e15`

  - **Can you check how much of that path is valid on your RedHat system?**

<sup>ps: I think this will be better answered at Superuser; but, don't make a second posting there, this might get moved.</sup>

---

Update:

- Use `whoami` or `id` to check if you are logged in as `root` or with your username

  - if you are not logged in as root, you can do a `root` login from another terminal
    or just `su - root` from that terminal; you will need to know the `root` password
- You can check if the error path is available on your system with a,
  `ls /lib/modules/2.6.18-53.e15/` etc

  - There will also be a `log.txt` file generated from your last compile attempt,
    this would have the `autorun.sh` outputs recorded for debug
    (so, you don't have to re-run the script to see them).
- `2.6.18-53.e15` is the kernel,
  Look at this LinuxQuestions thread on [Installing NIC drivers](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/installing-nic-drivers-725874/).
  **You seem to be missing the kernel sources for the driver compile to work.**
  that thread is discussing a similar problem with the `r8169` driver installation.

Comment: yaa u are right i picked up for 2.6 ..I dont know how to enter these all things so will u plz explain things little bit actully i am not able to use internet their or do my practical plz help me